# How to run my PHP interpreter on network files

Tags: php, localhost, network-drive

Is there a way to have your PHP interpreter (I'm using [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)) installed locally but have it run for files on the network? So I have...

- `C:\wamp\bin\php\phpx.x.xx\` (Local install)

and

- `Z:\www\example.com\index.php` (Network)

How can I open `index.php` in the browser and have it run the interpreter? Of course, the way I currently run things is saving to `C:\wamp\www\path\` and pull up `http://localhost/path/index.php` in the browser.

---

I'm wanting to avoid having to remote connect to my developer desktop to access local files there. I'd rather put my `.php` files on the network and work with them anywhere.

Comment: Can you mount nfs location on web dir..? then run program on web dir

Comment: @Girish — I don't think that's possible on a windows system. File systems can only be mounted on drive letters.

Comment: I understand most of those words... separately. :S

Comment: Everything I'm trying just keeps WAMP from restarting. I think it's hitting the Z: drive and being denied access since I have to be logged in to access it. I figure it's a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

The browser cannot involve the PHP interpreter. It talks to a webserver, the webserver runs PHP.

You can configure Apache to use whatever directories you like with various directives such as

```
DocumentRoot "Z:/www/example.com"
```

or

```
Alias /foo "Z:/www/example.com"
```

For development purposes, you may just wish to run the built in webserver on whatever machine you are working on:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Comment: bu if you also want c:\ as document root. You need extra virtual hosts. Am i wrong?

Comment: @hakkikonu — If you want multiple document roots, then yes, you'll need to have virtual hosts.

Comment: Would you happen to know where I can edit Apache's `DocumentRoot`? I know for certain I'm unable to change my computer's `host` file due to business restrictions.

Comment: Somewhere in its config file. I only really know my way around the Debian layout for the Apache config. No idea where it is on Windows. I don't think I've run Apache there since the 90s.

Comment: I'm finding `DocumentRoot` in an `httpd.conf` file, so I'm gonna try that real quick. Though I'd like to point an *additional* one: `http://localhost/network/` -> `Z:\www\ ` so as to not mess up my local one.

Comment: You can't have multiple document roots. You'd be trying to serve up two different resources for `http://example.com/`. Look at the other options in the answer or set up a virtual host.

Comment: Could you explain `php -S localhost:8000`. I know it looks like a console command, but I've never learned console.

Comment: You type that and it runs a webserver for running PHP with the document root in the current directory.

Comment: Bah, well, after changing `httpd.conf' to change `DocumentRoot` from `"c:/wamp/www/"` to `"n:/Dept/Team/Dev/APACHE/"` and also `<Directory "n:/Dept/Team/Dev/APACHE/">...</Directory>` and trying to restart my server, it stalls out and won't restart. Wampserver doesn't seem to like that network drive.

Answer (score 0):

Wamp uses Apache as web server and this web server has virtual host by default. If you add new virtual host for network it will work.

Also you can add alias to your Apache config

Answer (score 0):

Of course Quentin answer is good but I looked more into your problem and it's pretty typical.

You should consider using Control Version System like GIT and create Repository. Then put code there. Your developers will download it and run it on their own machines and you can check the files using for example GitLab or GitHub or any other service or even console.

In that configuration you can have:

1. Production enviroment where project stays and works
2. Stage - which is identical to production and you can check there changes before applying them in production
3. Dev where your developers write code.

Comment: Great suggestion. GIT is on my shortlist of things to dig more into. I'm the only dev here, so I struggle to understand concepts used my dev **teams** simply because there's no business incentive to use them, and my manager doesn't really expect me to learn version control outside of the CMS. I really need to find somewhere to work with a team to get that experience.

Comment: If you work in team and you don't use CVS then you are masochist :)

Comment: I can definitely see a benefit to using Git even as a lone dev, because it forces you to be more explicit with your changes, and three months down the road you really need to know what the heck you were thinking. I installed a Git plugin to SublimeText but had errors out of the box and just never got back to it.

Comment: of couse you can by installing git locally and using local features of git you can even put it to remote by yourself even if later you decide as team to use git you can have multiple remote repositories with GIT